# glDrawElements with Index Offset not working

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using OpenGL 4.3 version and setting up VBO and dynamically generating indexes ( I am using the same logic for generating an index for VBO from here https://github.com/huamulan/OpenGLtutorial/blob/master/common/vboindexer.cpp). Now I am having one big vector of all the vertices and One vector of Indexes.
Now coming to rendering part with glDrawElements, it is not working. I am getting distorted graphics.  Below is my code. Am I doing anything wrong with Index offsets?  With glDrawArrays( commented in the below code) it works fine. I get proper graphics. But not with glDrawElements.
is it something I cannot use glDrawelements in this case?

```
//My Data structure 
struct DisplayIndexID {
        int idx;
        DrawStateT drawState;
        //Every display Index ID has its own draw models.
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<vertexModel>> readytoDrawModels;
    };


void  initVbo(std::vector<DisplayIndexID> & v)

{
                        
    glBindVertexArray(geomVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, geomVBO);
    std::vector<QVector3D> vecToDraw;
    for (int j = 0; j < v.size(); j++)
        for (auto& vModel : v[j].readytoDrawModels)
        {
            if (vModel) {
                vecToDraw = vModel->getVertices();
                finalVecToDraw.insert(finalVecToDraw.end(), vecToDraw.begin(), vecToDraw.end());
                }
        }

    if (!finalVecToDraw.empty())
    {
        index(finalVecToDraw); // indexing logic is from the above link.
    
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(QVector3D) * out_vertices.size(), &out_vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, geomIBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, out_indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), &out_indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
// Draw Function

void draw(std::vector<DisplayIndexID> & v)
{
    
    GLintptr offset = 0;
    GLintptr indOffset = 0;
    
    initVbo(v);  //setting up VBOs data and index buffer.
    
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
      makeCurrent();
      bool isTextureUsed = false;

        //Apply Projection Matrix.
        GLint mvp_mat = 0;
        GLint mvp_matText = 0;

        ///***********PRINT AREA***********************/
        for (auto& vModel : v[i].readytoDrawModels)
        {

            if (vModel) 
            {
               glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
               mvp_mat = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mvp");
      glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_mat, 1, GL_FALSE, (m_projection * vModel->getModelState()).data());
            ...
            }

             glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, geomVBO);
             glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, geomIBO); 

             glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
             glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(QVector3D),(GLvoid*)offset);
             
             switch (vModel->getDrawMode())
                {
                case 0: //GL_POINTS
                    //glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vModel->getVertices().size());
             glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, out_indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void *)indOffset);
                break;

                case 1: //GL_LINES
                //glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, vModel->getVertices().size());
                glDrawElements(GL_LINES, out_indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void *)indOffset);
                break;
 
                case 2: //GL_LINE_LOOP
               //glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, vModel->getVertices().size());
           glDrawElements(GL_LINE_LOOP, out_indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void *)indOffset);
                break;
                case 3: //GL_TRIANGLES
                //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vModel->getVertices().size());
          glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, out_indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)indOffset);

          }  
          default:
                break;
          }
                
          glBindVertexArray(0);
       }
     }
       offset += sizeof(QVector3D) * vModel->getVertices().size();
       indOffset += sizeof(unsigned int) * out_indices.size();   // is this calculation correct?
 }
      
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    finalVecToDraw.clear();
    out_vertices.clear();
    out_indices.clear();        

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The pointer arithmetics are wrong. When you have a pointer to an unsigned int, then + 1 moves the pointer by `sizeof(unsigned int)`, but your code assumes that you are adding a byte offset to the pointer.

Example:

```
unsigned int* ptr = nullptr; //0x0
unsigned int* ptr2 = ptr + 1 //0x4, the next integer after ptr
```

So in your code you need to change this line

```
indOffset += sizeof(unsigned int) * out_indices.size();
```

into

```
indOffset += out_indices.size();
```